# How do I get the initial url of an ImageView formed from a Bitmap

Tags: android, android-imageview

Initially I created a bitmap from an external URL by using a `bitmapFactory`. I then put the bitmap in an Image view, like:

```
 ImageView mim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.moviepix);
 String mi = "http://xxxxxxx.com/"+ result.movie_pix;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new    URL(mi).getContent());
mim.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Now I need to reverse engineer the url from the `ImageView`.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, but you can however store the URL for later use with ImageView.setTag()